# Is it possible to build a mikvah for personal use as an orthodox Jew?

Tags: marriage, mikvah-ritual-bath

For example, if your wife would prefer not to use a public one and wants to install one in your house? Is there anything to be aware of if you're considering doing this?

Comment: Anything to be aware of besides all the laws of constructing a kosher mikvah?

Comment: Surely if you do everything they did in the public mikvah's construction and operation but in your basement, that would work. So the answer to your question would be yes it is possible. Is that really what you want to know?

Comment: @DoubleAA basically, yes! I was also perhaps hoping that someone who has either done this or who knows someone that has could suggest any good things to know going into it that might not occur to you on first glance.

Comment: Why not? A mikvah doesn't become kosher if it's public or private. It just has to he built according to the laws.

Comment: Rabbi Miller's book actually encouraged people to do this. There were many questions on his leniencies with the technical construction, but I don't think anyone objected to the concept per se of a private mikvah. The issue is just having a knowledgeable rabbi involved in the construction and maintenance.

Comment: Definitely yes.  Back in the early 1960s, a family down the block put a kosher private mikveh in their home.

Comment: A neighbor of mine has a Mike in his basement. As answers below make it clear, construction can only be done by experts, there are guides explaining the complexity of doing so that we can point you to if helpful

Answer (score 6):

The question seems to be not if it it theoretically possible to build a private mikva, but practically how to go about doing so. This is beyond the scope of a Q&A website, and that is not a new thing. The [Kitzar Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.162.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes about this:

> דִּינֵי הַמִּקְוֶה, רַבִּים הֵם מְאֹד. וּבְכָל מָקוֹם שֶׁעוֹשִׂין מִקְּוֶה, אֵין לַעֲשׂוֹתוֹ כִּי אִם עַל יְדֵי רַב מֻמְחֶה לָרַבִּים, גָּדוֹל בַּתּוֹרָה וּבְיִרְאָה. וְכַאֲשֶׁר יִתְהַוֶּה בוֹ אֵיזֶה שִׁנּוּי גָּדוֹל אוֹ קָטָן, יַעֲשׂוּ מִיָד שְׁאֵלַת חָכָם. וְכֵן כַּאֲשֶׁר יִצְטָרְכוּ לִשְׁאֹב אוֹתוֹ לְנַקּוֹתוֹ, יִשְׁאֲלוּ אֵיךְ יִתְנַהֲגוּ.
>
> The laws regarding mikvah are very numerous. Wherever a mikvah is being made, it should be constructed only under the supervision of a very renowned poseik, great in Torah and in fear of God. When any change occurs (in the mikvah), whether a minor or major (change), a competent poseik should be consulted immediately. Also, when it becomes necessary to draw the water in order to clean it, a poseik should be consulted about the proper way to do it.

Comment: A good answer might suggest companies or rabbis who specialize in this sort of thing, or perhaps realistic price estimates. This answer doesn't really help anyone

Comment: Hi @DoubleAA, I actually did find this answer somewhat insightful as I did not realize that you need to consult not just any rabbi but a renowned one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help, it gives the basics of what the Mikvah must have. I know Asher Meza had a video on someone building their own mikvah https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaLfc4VZIAM

https://www.ocjewish.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/440984/jewish/Construction-of-a-Mikvah.htm

Answer (score 1):

If it was built with the consultation and guidance of a knowledgeable Posek. There is another issue, that one would need a Mikava attendant to come in to make sure that the woman has toivled K'Halacha. The Noda BiYehuda permits a husband to do this and even to help her go to Mikva when there is no one else around.
However, if a woman is perfectly able to go to a regular Mikva or call an attendant from elsewhere for her private Mikva, her husband CANNOT be used just because she feels uncomfortable going to Mikva in front of her.
Please ask your local Rabbi as every case could have additional factors which we are unaware of.

Comment: While all recommend supervision of the dip, many don't actually require it.

Comment: To Double AA: can you please show me where I can read more about (supervision not required), this is very relevant nowadays bec. of Covid, thanks!

Comment: @user16403 Try Shulchan Arukh YD 198:40 but I don't see what covid has to do with anything. The supervisor can wear a mask and stay well over 6 feet away. There is no rational reason to be concerned. Not everything needs to be turned into a covid halachic emergency.

Answer (score -1):

it is not so hard for a mikva to become pasul - invalid - and without the constant supervision of a competent authority - which public mikvahs have - one can unknowingly transgress countless avairos each punishable by kores. who would want to take such a risk. modern mikvahs are more hygienic clean and comfortable than anything a private person would venture on his own.

Comment: I'd think it's pretty hard to invalidate a mikvah once it's built. Just don't pour anything colored into it and make sure the water level is still at the line. What am I missing? Those should be pretty straightforward for anyone to keep track of.

Comment: the water line does not have to lower drematically to invalidate a mikva. the water line will daturaly lower due to evaporation and immersing, and it is not easy to determine that the sealant remains 100% intact at all times

if the mikva was not 100% dry - after being cleaned with non mikva water - before refilling it could render the mikva as invalid.

refilling a mikva is a complicated issue.

Comment: Refilling the bor is just like starting anew but that's not at all common. Probably only every few years for a personal mikva that isn't being used every night.